# Accessing contents of an iframe that's loaded from a different source

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

Using jQuery and through a Chrome extension, I'm trying to access the contents of an iframe that is loaded dynamically from a PHP script and loads from a different source.

I can access the contents on the console with the code below but only if I click on the element and find it in the DOM.

```
$("#view-chat").find("span.msg-text").last().text();
```

I get `""` if I try the same code 
1. through the Chrome extension 
2. when the page loads
3. without navigating through the DOM to find the element.

Any ideas on how I can use the extension to access an iframe element?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can resolve this:

Make sure that the iframe will be of the same source, pointing to a page of your site, let's call it yourproxy. Now, this of course means that the browser will send a request to yourproxy due to the iframe.

So far so good. Now, on yourproxy you need to send a request (maybe a cURL request) to the page that you want to load and put its contents into your iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lajos. I think accessing the contents is actually not allowed because of _cross-site scripting_. Since I don't have control over the source of the iframe I get the error `Blocked a frame with origin... from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: @bamerf the point of my answer was that you could load your page inside the iframe instead of the other source, but your page, on the server-side would happen to send a request to the other source and send the result to the browser. You will not have cross-origin problem on your server, so you can extract the content of the page there and display that in your iframe.

Comment: @bamerf in other words, you would delegate the task of downloading content from the foreign source to the server and display the results in the iframe as your page. You create a page and request it inside an iframe. You would not have cross-origin problems in that case, because the origin is the same. But your page from your origin that is loaded inside the iframe on server-side would send a request to the foreign origin. In short, you would create a page which would operate as a proxy to bypass the cross-origin problem of the browser.